# Can a point on a curve always be mapped to another point with trivial residue map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-cohomology

The following construction is taken from the book *Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology* by Gille and Szamuely in Chapter 6.4:

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over a perfect field $k$ with function field $K$. For an algebraic closure $\bar{k}$ of $k$, let $\bar{C} := C \times_k \bar{k}$ and let $G := \mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$. The function field of $\bar{C}$ is by definition the composite $K\bar{k}$.

Let $C_0$ denote the closed points of $C$. For $P \in C_0$, $G$ permutes the closed points $Q$ in $\bar{C}_0$ lying over $P$, so we get a decomposition $$\mathrm{Div}(\bar{C}) = \bigoplus _{P \in C_0} \left(\bigoplus_{Q \mapsto P}\mathbb{Z} \right).$$ Therefore for each $i \geq 0$, the divisor map $(K\bar{k})^\times \rightarrow \mathrm{Div}(\bar{C})$ induces the map $$H^i(G,(K\bar{k})^\times) \rightarrow \bigoplus _{P \in C_0} H^i \left(G,\bigoplus_{Q \mapsto P}\mathbb{Z} \right) \cong \bigoplus _{P \in C_0}H^i(G_P,\mathbb{Z}),$$
where $G_P \subset G$ denotes the stabilizer of a fixed $Q$ in $\bar{C}$ and the last map follows from Shapiro's lemma. For $i \geq 2$, it is well-known that $H^i(G_P,\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^{i-1}(G_P,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. For our case, we fix $i=2$ and a $P \in C_0$ to obtain the *residue map* $$r_P: H^2(G, (K\bar{k})^\times) \rightarrow H^1(G_P,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) = \mathrm{Hom}(G_P,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}).$$ By our construction, we know that such maps are trivial for all but finitely many $P$.

**Question.** If $r_P$ is non-trivial, can we find an automorphism $\tau: C \rightarrow C$ and a $P' \in C_0$ such that $\tau(P) = P'$ and $r_{P'}$ is trivial?

Note that this is automatically true when $C$ is an elliptic curve. Also, for a curve of genus $\geq 2$, it is known that it has finitely many automorphisms, so if the answer to the question is affirmative, it would not be straightforward (to me).

Comment: I am a little puzzled by this. In the line ``For $P \in C_0$, $G$ permutes the closed points $Q$ in $\bar{C}_0$ lying over $P$, so we get a decomposition $$\mathrm{Div}(\bar{C}) = \bigoplus _{P \in C_0} \left(\bigoplus_{Q \mapsto P}\mathbb{Z} \right).$$'' The Galois group $G=Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ will permute the set $C_0$ of closed points of $C$. So in particular, if $P$ is not $k$-rational, $G$ may not take $P$ to $P$, hence may not take the fiber over $P$ to itself. So the line ''$G$ permutes the closed points $Q$ in $\bar{C}_0$ lying over $P$'' may not be true. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EvansGambit If $P$ is not rational, then $[\kappa (P):k] = n \geq 2$. Does this mean that the fiber of $P$ in $\bar{C}$ would have size $n$? I understand your confusion but the book did not mention anything about $G$ also permuting the closed points of $C$. Perhaps I need to find out how such a permutation is defined, I need to think about it.

Comment: $G$ is acting on the points of $\overline{C}$ as follows: There is a map $G \to Aut(K\overline{k}/K)$ by extending the action of $G$ on $\overline{k}$ to the compositum $K\overline{k}$ by acting as Identity on $K$. Now a closed point $Q$ on $\overline{C}$ defines a valuation on its function field $K\overline{k}$, precomposing with the action of an element of $G$ via above map, gives another valuation on $K\overline{k}$, hence a closed point on the curve $\overline{C}$. Now it is easy to see, this action similarly defined will fix the closed points of $C$. So things are alright on that front!